# how to rotate labels of chart axis in wpf toolkit c# code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, rotation, axis

I try to rotate the text in the axis from horizontal to vertical but it doesn't work? Where i'm wrong?

```
LinearAxis lin = new LinearAxis();

var rotateLabel = new Style(typeof(AxisLabel));
var setter = new Setter(AxisLabel.RenderTransformProperty,
             new RotateTransform() { Angle = -90, CenterX = 15, CenterY = 10 });

rotateLabel.Setters.Add(setter);
lin.AxisLabelStyle = rotateLabel;

chart.Axes.Add(lin);
```

I want to rotate x axe labels but this code doesn't do anything (i want vertical view for labels).

Comment: not too sure what you're trying to do ... why don't you just use the other axis? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want make change of x labels instead of horizontal view i need vertical view (so i try rotation with angle of 90 degree). Labels are strings (for example first value is 16:30:4.5, but next value goes overlap first one so it is hard to see if it is horizontal kind of label view).